IllegalStateException while Logging into vCenter Using VMware SDK API
While using the VMware SDK API to log in, I'm occasionally encountering a java.lang.IllegalStateException. I'm unsure of the cause. Can anyone provide assistance or insights on this issue?
I have experimented with a single VMWARE connection to retrieve metrics using multi-threading, and I close the connection prior to fetching the metrics using VimPortType but cannot able to replicate the issue.
Code for login:
vimPort.login(serviceContent.getSessionManager(), userName, password, null);

JAXP API version - 1.4.2
Exception Trace:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are running with invalid JAXP api or implementation. JAXP api/implementation of version 1.3.1 (included in JDK6) or higher is required. In case you are using ant, make sure ant 1.7.0 or higher is used - older versions of ant contain JAXP api/impl version 1.2 (in xml-apis.jar). If you want to keep using older ant versions, you have to configure it to use higher the JAXP api/impl versions.
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createTransformerFactory(XmlFactory.java:191)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.createTransformerHandler(JAXBContextImpl.java:738)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader$State.(DomLoader.java:75)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.DomLoader.startElement(DomLoader.java:118)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.ProxyLoader.startElement(ProxyLoader.java:60)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:577)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleStartElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:246)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:180)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:415)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:386)
at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.readPayloadAsJAXB(StreamMessage.java:299)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.message.MessageWrapper.readPayloadAsJAXB(MessageWrapper.java:161)
at com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.create(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:523)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.StubHandler.readResponse(StubHandler.java:222)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:176)
at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.deserializeResponse(DatabindingImpl.java:263)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:62)
at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:131)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.login(Unknown Source)`

